# How to properly create groups using Microsoft Graph?

Tags: rest, office365, microsoft-graph-api

The request to

> POST v1.0/groups

with the body:

```
{
    "description": "hello",
    "displayName": "group_for_restore",
    "groupTypes": [
        "Unified"
    ],
    "mailEnabled": true,
    "mailNickname": "group_for_restore",
    "securityEnabled": false,
    "visibility": "Public"
}
```

returns the **id** of the created group. But on the web interface this group does not appear.
That is why the request to

> POST v1.0/planner/plans

with the body:

```
{
  "owner": "{group-id}", // from the request above
  "title": "group_for_restore"
}
```

returns such JSON:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "You do not have the required permissions to access this item, or the item may not exist.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "d6d74776-e4cc-4cb2-bf87-20e3510b6f8c",
            "date": "2018-03-27T14:39:00"
        }
    }
} (status code 403)
```

So it seems to me that it failed to create whole group (with all necessary content). I was trying to wait (2-5 min ... when the group will appear on the web interface), after that I could easily create a plan.
How can I properly guess the time when a group will be created or which request should be sent to check that it has been created successfully?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't "guess", instead use periodic polling.

After creating the group, try polling `groups/{id}/drive` in 2-5 minute intervals. Once the Drive is available the Group has been provisioned.

Comment: After creating a group according to your suggestion I tried immediately send request to get drive info and it succeeded! But group did not appear on the web interface and I still cannot create a plan.

Comment: Are you an owner of the group?

Comment: I'm not sure why you say "of course". Have you confirmed this by looking at the `/owners` endpoint? Also, which "web interface" are you referring too?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Office365 web interface (office365->Outlook->People->Groups)